# Can't add group to user

Tags: 20.04, users, groups

For ROCm 4.0 in Ubuntu 20.04 I need to add the 'render' group to the user. I do this with

```
pete@black:~$ groups
pete adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare
pete@black:~$ sudo usermod -a -G render pete
pete@black:~$ groups
pete adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare
```

Why was the group not added?

Digging further:

```
$ sudo grep pete /etc/group
adm:x:4:syslog,pete
cdrom:x:24:pete
sudo:x:27:pete
dip:x:30:pete
video:x:44:pete
plugdev:x:46:pete
render:x:109:pete
lpadmin:x:120:pete
lxd:x:131:pete
pete:x:1000:
sambashare:x:132:pete
```

Looks like the user is in the group 'render'. But the user doesn't seem to have the privileges:

```
pete@black$ /opt/rocm/bin/rocminfo 
ROCk module is loaded
Unable to open /dev/kfd read-write: Permission denied



$ ll -l /dev/kfd
crw-rw---- 1 root render 238, 0 Jan 17 23:28 /dev/kfd
```

I closed all terminals and opened a fresh one. Same thing.

Now comes the weird part: When I 'su' into the user, then it works:

```
pete@black:~$ groups
pete adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare
pete@black:~$ su pete
Password: 
pete@black:~$ groups
pete adm cdrom sudo dip video plugdev render lpadmin lxd sambashare
```

What happens differently when I 'su' into that user compared to launching a new 'Terminal'? (Again: I close the Terminal and launch a new one and the group 'render' is missing!!)

Edit: And even: I logged out of Ubuntu (Gnome I guess?) completely and logged back in. Launching a Terminal and the group is missing! (but can bring it back with 'su pete'.)

Answer (score 2):

A reboot solved it. As mentioned logging completely out and in again did not help.